# rollaplly for time series

Tags: r, rollapply

I have a data set with 358 rows, a quick look is as follows

```
>        unempts gdpts
> [1,]    7.03   4.2
> [2,]    7.17   3.7
> [3,]    6.97   3.2
> [4,]    6.83   2.9
> [5,]    6.60   2.7
> [6,]    6.27   3.4
```

I need to run a regression of Column 1 on Column 2, for 60 rolling windows and save all results in matrix so that I can plot the same and run `HAC`.

I tried the following:

```
regRO <- rollapply(datam, 60, lm, by.column = TRUE,fill=NA)
```

but get an error as follows

> Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

Please advise what needs to be changed.

Comment: Which packages did you use? Or is it a typo. I cannot find `rollapplyr`.

Comment: I used the package zoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the function call explicitly so that `X` is first converted to a data frame to satisfy the input requirements of `lm`:

```
library(zoo)

set.seed(123) # ensure runif in next line uses same random numbers each time run
datam <-matrix(runif(200),ncol=2)

out <- rollapplyr(datam,
          width = 60,
          FUN = function(X) coef(lm(as.data.frame(X))),
          by.column=FALSE,
          fill = NA) # omit fill=NA if NA rows not wanted
```

giving:

```
> tail(out)
       (Intercept)         V2
[95,]    0.5071618 -0.1041905
[96,]    0.5015140 -0.1032419
[97,]    0.5196683 -0.1404855
[98,]    0.5171599 -0.1401534
[99,]    0.5122871 -0.1288700
[100,]   0.5176396 -0.1297019
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck , the above worked and the summary I get is  (Intercept)           V2         
 Min.   :0.3260   Min.   :0.06008  
 1st Qu.:0.3576   1st Qu.:0.11453  
 Median :0.3756   Median :0.21695  
 Mean   :0.3957   Mean   :0.20331  
 3rd Qu.:0.4404   3rd Qu.:0.29501  
 Max.   :0.4985   Max.   :0.33402  
 NA's   :59       NA's   :59 , so now I want to cull out all the slope coefficents into a vector so plot the same. How do I call that. Should I try     regRO=matrix(out)$coefficents[2,1]

Comment: You can get the slope (beta) with this: `plot(na.omit(out[,2]),type="l")`

Comment: @ P Lapointe, my understanding of the the code above as given by G.Grothendieck is as follows: 1-Install library(zoo), 2-set.seed(123)?? 3-create matrix called datam has 200 rows, with uniform intervals ( so i can change as per my data set), and 2 columns. out is the new object created in which we use rollapply function ( on datam dataset, with a rolling window of 60, FUN=?? , using the the function of regression (on the data frame X), not applying the rolling window to each column??) So the part I did not understand is X, coef() and why by.coulm is false, since lm should take both columns.

Comment: also why do we use set.seed, when the data set is given and there are no random numbers?

Comment: You don't need set.seed(). Gabor didn't like that I included results that were not reproducible (because runif() generates different numbers every time it is run). He edited my answer and added set.seed(). However, he also ended up removing the part where I showed the results.

Comment: Just to be clear, I created dummy data because your data was not reproducible. It's just to illustrate how it works. Use your own datam. As for  `by.column=FALSE`, ?rollapplyr tells you: If TRUE, FUN is applied to each column separately.You want FUN to use both columns for the regression. TRUE would be if you wanted to run a moving average on single columns.

Comment: Non-reproducible output was posted so I intentionally removed it.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck I understand why you removed the non-reproducible output. I was just mentioning that the set.seed(123) you added was not necessary since there was no output anymore. Cheers.

Comment: It was necessary to make the example reproducible regardless of whether the output is actually shown or not.

Comment: @PLapointe, now I need to get the HAC SE for the rolling window, for which I tried the below code

Comment: @PLapointe basically I can't identify the object from the above code so that I can use it to extract further data like standard errors etc..